# Using the Microsoft Band Tile Designer Preview with SubscribeToBackgroundTileEventsAsync

Tags: microsoft-band

What would be the way to use the Designer Preview when we use the SubscribeToBackgroundTileEventsAsync method?
In the current version the app project needs to contain the designer and the code file (the current version of the designer does not support putting the generated code in a shared project). The app project needs a reference to the service project, but the service project needs access to the generated code in the app project if I want to update the information shown on the tile. Visual Studio (obviously) won't let me add a reference to the app project in the service project because of a circular reference.